# Vuetify routing: changing page content conundrum

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vue-router, router

I desire to see the content of `uwc.vue` upon clicking the **"Let's GO"** button (which is in `App.vue`).
But, the url changes & the content's of the screen still remain the same.

I am new to vue, I asked this question to the Vuetify community but it was ignored.

Thank you in advance.

**router.js**:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Router from 'vue-router';
import uwc from '../views/uwc';

Vue.use(Router);

export default new Router({
    mode: 'history',
    routes: [
        { path: '/', name: 'uwc', component: uwc},
    ]
});
```

**App.vue**

```
<template>
    <v-app>
        <v-container fluid>
            <v-col class="d-flex mx-auto" >
                <!-- UWC Card -->
                <v-card class="mx-auto my-15" max-width="400" >
                    <v-img height="400px" class="image-fit" src="./img/UWC-logo.webp" ></v-img>
                    <v-divider class="mx-4"></v-divider>
                    <v-card-title>
                        <p class="text-break">
                            University of the Western Cape
                        </p>
                    </v-card-title>                
                    <v-card-actions>
                        <router-link to="/views/uwc">
                            Let's GO
                        </router-link>
                    </v-card-actions> 
                </v-card>
            </v-col>
        </v-container>
    </v-app>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'app',
    }
</script>
```

**uwc.vue** (*the file I want to display on clicking the **"Let's GO"** button*):

```
<template>
    <v-app  id="inspire">
        <router-view></router-view>
        <v-container fluid>
            <v-row>
                <template v-for="n in 4">
                    <v-col :key="n" class="mt-2" cols="12">
                        <strong> Category {{ n }} </strong>
                    </v-col>
                    <v-col v-for="j in 6" :key="`${n}${j}`" cols="6"  md="2">
                        <v-sheet height="150"></v-sheet>
                    </v-col>
                </template>
            </v-row>
        </v-container>
    </v-app>
</template>
```

Comment: You don't have view with path /views/uwc defined in router.js `routes` array

Comment: Thank you for your assistance.
The issue is resolved thanks to you and the answer below from Riza.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, this isn't a 'Vuetify' question. Its a general routing question for VueJS.

Your primary problem is that you do not have a `<router-view/>` in your App.vue file. This is what renders the paths in your router.

App.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <router-view/>    
  </div>
</template>
```

Now if you visit the '/' path, you will see the contents of your uwc.vue file.

I also wanted to point out another error.

Your `<router-link></router-link>` tags refer to the `path` in your router file, not the path to the file is located in your folder structure.

You have:

`<router-link to="views/uwc">`

Should be:

`<router-link to="/">`

If you are continuing to struggle, create a brand new app using the [Vue CLI][1].

Then add the router using `vue add router`. It will give you a pretty solid example to work off of on your app.
[1]: https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/creating-a-project.html#vue-create

Comment: Awesome! Do you mind marking this question as the correct one?